# Finding a Certain Length Cycle in a Undirected Graph - TSP

Tags: graph, graph-theory, np

I have 80 nodes and I need to find a cycle of length 40 from these, while keeping the distance  traveled by the cycle to a minimum. Some nodes cannot directly connect, they're in specific areas and I can only travel from one area to another, not within one area.

I'm just asking in general here, what kind of techniques can I use to get the best (shortest) possible cycle of 40 nodes? So far I've written a basic substitution optimizer and just a greedy DFS. I'm wondering what would be the best approach for me to start on now?

Comment: I guess you could create an 80×80 matrix and take its 40th power, that would at least tell you how many cycles there are and which their starting nodes are.

Comment: What exactly do you mean take its 40th power?

Comment: Matrix multiplication allows you to take the 40th power of a square matrix. I think in this special case you don't even have to worry about associativity so you can just multiply the 32nd power by the 8th power.